# Send mail using Mailchimp's API

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I created a mail campaign(chose "automated" and "API")

[image]

When I try to send a test mail

```
post: https://us20.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns/{my_campaign_id}/actions/test
```

I get a `400`, "**Cannot send this campaign because it is currently sending**" error.

And in the dashboard I can see the status of the campaign is "Sending".

[image]

The edit mode of the campaign there is only an option to pause the campaign.

Here is the code(using Node.js) used to send the mail

```
const request = require('superagent');

request.post(`https://us20.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns/${CAMPAIGN_ID}/actions/test`)
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8')
    .set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + new Buffer('any:' + MAILCHIMP_API_KEY).toString('base64'))
    .send({
        test_emails: [ 'my_mail@gmail.com' ],
        send_type: 'html',
    })
    .end((error, response) => {
        if (error) {
            res.send({ error });
        } else {
            res.send({ data: response });
        }
    });
```

Could you guys point out how to fix the "sending" error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the MailChimp automation documents you should first pauze the campaign before you can edit it's properties.

I guess you have to wait untill the campaign is done sending before you can send a testmail on it: https://mailchimp.com/help/troubleshooting-automations/.